# Give me a sample on Long-polling(Comet) with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, comet, long-polling

Recently I am studying ajax. I'm curious about Long-polling. I know simple polling ,and I have  make a demo (send a request every 5 seconds.).But Long-polling ,There is a pivotal step that Server-Side can suspend the request until the data update . **So I wannt know how to suspend the request??** 
I am a Front-End developer . I'm poor about Server-Side. Just know basic Rails only.I find some samples but they all use PHP or JAVA....
Anybody can give me a demo that use Long-polling with Rails?